# How to make dots on input PIN showing character amount to provide?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

I need to create input with dots showing amount of characters required, and to hide one after other when characters provided:

[image]

What is the best way to do this?

I haven't come up with anything smart but drawing circles with `position: absolute` and add/remove them with js (on keydown or change). But that could fail, because of difference of character width (for ex. `i` and `W`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because @Santi proposed you the solution with jQuery, I've made a [jsFiddle with usage of angular](http://jsfiddle.net/dorzepowski/Lvc0u55v/10419/).

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span class="mask">•••••</span>
  <span class="hider">{{val}}</span>
  <input type="text" class="code" ng-model="val" maxlength="5" />
</div>
```

So I've created input which has no border and outline.
Below it on the bottom there is a span **mask** which has dots that you want. And above mask there is a **hider** where angular writes value from input so the background rise with the content and hide dots in mask span.

If you use angular in your project you could probably change my jsFiddle to directive.

Additionally IMHO it could be easly changed to jQuery option or even to pure javascript;

*PS. Please be respectful for me, because I'm not very best in css.*

Answer (score 1):

If you set the font-family of your input field to a monospace font, for example Courier, every character will be the same size. Then you can size your dots based on the ch unit. 1ch is the width of the 0 character (and thus every character in a monospace font).

If you don't want to draw circles, you might be able to use JavaScript to swap out bullets (•) each time a new character is input.

Answer (score 1):

I think your easiest and cleanest method might be implementing something like [**MasekdInput**](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). Check out the Demo section towards the bottom.

It's a JQuery plugin that puts placeholders into your inputs, and allows you to specify the placeholder character. By default it's `_`, but you could easily change it to be `•` by doing the following...

```
   $("#myTextField").mask("*****",{placeholder:"•"});
```